# Python: "Binning" subarrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, sub-array

I am seeking to make a kind of binning of lines of data according to the first element of the line.

My data has this shape:

```
[[Temperature, value0, value1, ... value249]
 [Temperature, ...
]
```

So to say: The first element of each line is a temperature value, the rest of the line is a time trace of a signal.

I would like to make an array of this shape:

```
[Temperature-bin,[[values]
                  [values]
                     ... ]]
 Next Temp.-bin, [[values]
                  [values]
                     ... ]]
...
]
```

where the lines from the original data-array should be sorted in the subarray of the respective temperature bin.

```
data= np.array([values]) # shape is [temp+250 timesteps,400K]
temp=data[0]

start=23000
end=380000

tempmin=np.min(temp[start:end])
tempmax=np.max(temp[start:end])

binsize=1
bincenters=np.arange(np.round(tempmin),np.round(tempmax)+1,binsize)

binneddata=np.empty([len(bincenters),2])

for i in np.arange(len(temp)):
    binneddata[i]=[bincenters[i],np.array([])]
```

I was hoping to get a result array as described above, where every line consists of the mean temperature of the bin (bincenters[i]) and an array of time traces. Python gives me an error regarding "setting an array element with a sequence.
I could create this kind of array, consisting of different data types, in another script before, but there I had to define it specifically, which is not possible in this case because I'm handling files on the scale of several 100K lines of data. At the same point I would like to use as many built-in functions and the least possible loops, because my computer is already taking some time to process files of that size.

Thank you for your input,

lepakk

Comment: What do you mean exacly by *time trace*?

Comment: I mean a series of values, like a curve obtained by an oscilloscope. I wanted to point out, that a line in the datafile has different types of data, i.e. 250 values are consecutive pieces of that oscilloscope curve and then there are some more numbers of different kind (for instance: temperature).

Comment: It seems like you're trying to use NumPy arrays like a data table, but this isn't really the best use of NumPy. You might be better off with separate arrays for the bins and the data, or with a `pandas` dataframe, or with a dictionary mapping bin to data, or with some other data structure. It would help to know what your goals is with this proposed array.

Comment: Later on I would like to do different things with the sub-arrays (the binned data). One thing is adding all lines in each of the sub-arrays and fit the resulting curves, but also counting events in the the bins, compare size of the sub-arrays... I'm not yet sure, what else, but it will be always playing around with the data within one sub-array and then compare the results of this vs the temperature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: Thanks to kwinkunks for the hint of using a pandas dataframe.
I found a solution using this feature.

The binning is now done like this:

```
tempmin=np.min(temp[start:end])
tempmax=np.max(temp[start:end])

binsize=1
bincenters=np.array(np.arange(np.round(tempmin),np.round(tempmax)+1,binsize))
lowerbinedges=np.array(bincenters-binsize/2)
higherbinedges=np.array(bincenters+binsize/2)

allbinedges=np.append(lowerbinedges,higherbinedges[-1])

temp_pd=pd.Series(temp[start:end])
traces=pd.Series(list(data[start:end,0:250]))


tempbins=pd.cut(temp_pd,allbinedges,labels=bincenters)

df=pd.concat([temp_pd,tempbins,traces], keys=['Temp','Bincenter','Traces'], axis=1)
```

by defining bins (in this case even-sized). The variable "tempbins" is of the same shape as temp (the "raw" temperature) and assignes every line of data to a certain bin.

The actual analysis is then extremely short. Starting with:

```
rf=pd.DataFrame({'Bincenter': bincenters})
```

the resultframe ("rf") starts with the bincenters (as the x-axis in a plot later), and simply adds columns for the desired results.

With

```
df[df.Bincenter==xyz]
```

I can select only those data lines from df, that I want to have in the selected bin.

In my case, I am not interested in the actual time traces, but in the sum or the average, so I use lambda-functions, that run through the rows of rf and searches for every row in df, that has the same value in "Bincenter" there.

```
rf['Binsize']=rf.apply(lambda row: len(df.Traces[df.Bincenter==row.Bincenter]), axis=1)
rf['Trace_sum']=rf.apply(lambda row: sum(df.Traces[df.Bincenter==row.Bincenter]), axis=1)
```

With those, another column is added to the resultframe rf for the sum of the traces and the number of lines in the bin.

I performed some fits of the traces in rf.Trace_sum, which I did not in pandas.

Still, the dataframe was very useful here. I used odr for fitting like this

```
for i in binnumber:
    fitdata=odr.Data(time[fitstart:],rf.Trace_sum.values[i][fitstart:])
    ... some more fit stuff here...
```

and saved the fitresults in

```
lifetimefits=pd.DataFrame({'lifetime': fitresult[:,1], 'sd_lifetime':fitresult[:,4]})
```

and finally added them in the resultframe with

```
rf=pd.concat([rf,lifetimefits],axis=1)
rf[['Bincenter','Binsize','lifetime','sd_lifetime']].to_csv('results.csv', header=True, index=False)
```

which makes an output like

```
Out[78]: 
    Bincenter  Binsize  ...   lifetime  sd_lifetime
0       139.0     4102  ...  38.492028     2.803211
1       140.0     4252  ...  33.659729     2.534872
2       141.0     3785  ...  31.220312     2.252104
3       142.0     3823  ...  29.391562     1.783890
4       143.0     3808  ...  40.422578     2.849545
```

I hope, this explanation might help others to not waste time, trying this with numpy. Thanks again to kwinkunks for his very helpful advice to use the pandas DataFrame.

Best,
lepakk